# Call an array from object

Tags: arrays

```
-(NSMutableArray *) botanicalPlant {
if (_botanicalPlant == nil) {
    _botanicalPlant = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Abelia", nil];
   }
return _botanicalPlant;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

self.botanicalPlantName = [[BotanicalPlant alloc] init];
self.botanicalPlantNameLabel.text = []
}
```

I know this may be a simple question but Im stuck on this one. I have an array in NSObject of Botanical I just don't know how to call it in the viewDidLoad method for it to show up in my main view controller. I don't know what to put in the brackets to assign it to the text of the label.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown enough code to answer your question for sure.  But if `botanicalPlant` is a mutable array property on the `BotanicalPlant` class, then you could do something like:

```
BotanicalPlant *myBotanicalPlant = [[BotanicalPlant alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *namesArray = myBotanicalPlant.botanicalPlant;
self.botanicalPlantNameLabel.text = [namesArray firstObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

In your viewDidLoad method

```
 NSMutableArray *arrayFromBotanicalMethod = [self botanicalPlant];

// Then set the text label from your new array that you created

self.botanicalPlantNameLabel.text = [arrayFromBotanicalMethod objectAtIndex:0];
```

This code is based on the limited information you provided. You basically create another array that will hold the returned array from your botanicalPlant method. Then you use the objectAtIndex message on the new array to get the text for the label.

Hope it helps.

Comment: One minor correction: "You basically create another array that will hold the returned array" is incorrect.  "You create a reference to the  returned array" would be correct.  They are two different pointers to the same array; no copies are made.